# How to constrain Leaflet Popup to map container?

Tags: leaflet, popup

I'm working on a Leaflet app with a large number of markers (2000+) from a GeoJSON layer distributed around a city. The layer has popups with images and some information about the individual markers, and zooms the map on the marker following a click event. However, in some cases the popup goes above the top of the map, forcing the user to scroll the map down to be able to see all the content. Is there anyway to constrain the popup to the map container?

Comment: There is some autoPan properties that you could play around with. However, when I have used it before it caused a slow drift and sometimes shakes. Ended up feeling moving the map manually made the experience better. 
Here you can find the available properties for a popup 
https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup

Comment: cheers for the tip and reference.